# Show button after X seconds video JS

Tags: javascript, button, video

I'm trying to show a button after 10 seconds video. So when the video start, after 10 seconds of video play, it show my button

My button ID is `#btn`
My video ID is `#video`

I tried this but doesn't works :

```js
const TIME_TO_SHOW_BUTTON = 10; // 60 seconds;
const video = document.getElementById('#video');

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function showButton() {
  if (video.currentTime > TIME_TO_SHOW_BUTTON) {
    $('#showBlock').click(function(e) {
        $('#btn').show("slow");
    video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', showButton);
  }
});
```

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is _not_ an appropriate problem description. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please also use the Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet to or a link to jsFiddle.net simple copy because without both HTML and Javascript it's impossible to understand how it's supposed to operate

Comment: When clicking on #showBlock you will show a button if the time is greater then TIME_TO_SHOW_BUTTON? Will not work if you expect it to appear by itself

Comment: If you want the `#btn` button to show automatically why did you put `$('#btn').show("slow");` inside the `#showBlock` click listener?

Comment: You might get a faster if you **show complete testable** code (HTML & JS code in one page that can be tested immediately). Your problem is a button but there is zero setup of button code to check... Is your `<button>` in a div? You want to make a div visible after 10 seconds? Should we keep guessing...??